# Why super() is calling constructor of class Parent1 only and not calling constructor of class Parent2?

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child, super, base-class

```
class Parent1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data1 = 10
        print("parent1")

class Parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data2 = 20 
        print("parent2")

class child(Parent2,Parent1):
    def __init__(self):
        print("this is child class")
        super().__init__()
        print(self.data1)
        print(self.data2)
        
obj = child()
```

Output:

```
this is child class
parent2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:/Project2020/Rough Work/rough2.py", line 18, in <module>
    obj = child()
  File "f:/Project2020/Rough Work/rough2.py", line 15, in __init__
    print(self.data1)
AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute 'data1'
```

Comment: `Parent2.__init__` doesn't call `super().__init__`, so `Parent1.__init__` does not get called.

Comment: When you're designing for multiple inheritance, *all* classes need to be invoking the super implementations in their methods.

Comment: why super().__init__() is not calling __init__() of Parent2 class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question: in python there is an inheritance chain.  In your case this inheritance chain looks like [Child, Parent2, Parent1],
so kinda for the python compiler there's no such thing as multiple inheritance. `super()` is just a short-hand to walk one step up the inheritance chain. Therefore your statement is equal to `Parent2.__init__()` and indeed `super().__init__()` calls `Parent2.__init__()` as it should.
So you also need to call `Parent1.__init__()` from class `Child`.

I suggest writing:

```
class Parent1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data1 = 10
        print("parent1")

class Parent2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data2 = 20 
        print("parent2")

class Child(Parent2,Parent1):
    def __init__(self):
        print("this is child class")
        Parent2.__init__(self)
        Parent1.__init__(self)
        print(self.data1)
        print(self.data2)
```

In this situation the code is clearer if you don't use `super()`. This code may look odd but here using `super()` would be just confusing anyway.

Comment: Your approach is very good. Does super() calls only first parent class __init__()?

Comment: I am satisfied with your answer. Can you help me with this problem too-https://stackoverflow.com/q/66028530/12945919  . It is also based on super() and multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks. I see I cannot answer your question there because people closed it. (So, I'll answer it here, and if it helps you, put a +1 here).

So, since your object has the inheritance chain [Class4, Class2, Class3, Class1], the super() walks *that* chain and not the corresponding class'es chain as you'd naturally expect.

Comment: In fact, you could call even `Class2.m(my_object)` and then `super()` would just walk `my_object`-s chain, potentially outputting some even weirder stuff.

Comment: My question is here - https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/DNTVYZRn7B. Please look at it.